# Windows batch file output to another file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to list all the files in a directory excluding the extension. I would like to output this into a txt file. I have managed to list all the files successfully.

```
@ECHO OFF
for %%a in ("c:\wamp64\www\blessd\final\*") do ECHO %%~na
```

This works fine and all the files in the directory are printed to the screen, however when I try output this to a txt file it does not work.

```
for %%a in ("c:\wamp64\www\blessd\final\*") do ECHO %%~na > test1.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redirect the output of the bat file, not of a single output. If your bat file is `My.bat`, try:

```
My.bat > this.out
```